# Insert a 40x5 matrix to a 3 dimensions array of 1000x1000x3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a python code which will create a 1000x1000x3 3D array, I am trying to replace a 40x5 matrix to that 1000x1000x3 3d array on some specific location. For one element I am able to replace, but how to replace a 40x5 array.

Lets take this example

```
myarray = 1000,1000,3
matrix = 40x5 (this array code will generate)
insert position = 100th row of 10 th line
```

Comment: I have mentioned in the example "myarray = 1000,1000,3" please read the full question.

Comment: You can't update a sinlge location with that array. The result must be homogeneous throughout all axes. Otherwise you'll end up with a jagged array

Comment: @yatu you mean only one dimension only get replaced, right?

Comment: What output are you expecting? What do you mean with updating a single location? Are you talking about an axis? What will be the output shape?

Comment: Like an example I have a 3D array with 100x100 also i have a small 1D array of 10x10 i need to replace the 100x100 (eg: location will be like 50th column on 10th row) with this 10x10 array values in all 3 dimensions, sorry if I am confusing.

Answer (score 0):

For 2D images it can work like this.

```
myarray = np.arange(36).reshape(6,6)
matrix = np.zeros((2,2))
x_dim, y_dim = matrix.shape()
start_x = 1
start_y = 2

myarray[start_y:start_y + y_dim, start_x:start_x + x_dim] = matrix 

out: array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
            [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
            [12,  0,  0, 15, 16, 17],
            [18,  0,  0, 21, 22, 23],
            [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
            [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
```

If you have a 3-dimensional array you can acces the individual "layers" via:

```
layer_id = 1 
myarray[layer_id][start_y:start_y + y_dim, start_x:start_x + x_dim] = matrix
```

If you want to have the matrix inprinted in each layer you can loop over the layer-axis:

```
for layer_id in myarray:
     myarray[layer_id][start_y:start_y + y_dim, start_x:start_x + x_dim] = matrix
```

Comment: can we do this for a 3d array, because my array is in 3d.

Comment: thanks jorn, Let me try that, thanks for the timely help.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy advanced indexing:

```
r, c = matrix.shape
#insert position row and column
idx = [insert_row,insert_column]
myarray[idx[0]:idx[0]+r, idx[1]:idx[1]+c, :] = matrix[:,:,None]
```

Example:

```
myarray = np.zeros((5,5,3))
matrix = np.ones((2,3))
idx = [1,2]
```

output:

```
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Comment: Ehsan I am new to SO, I upvoted your answer but i think i don't have the access as off now to do so,